# Visually distinguish different lines (for long wrapped lines) in iTerm2 / Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, iterm

I'm using an application that outputs very long lines. It's fine - it means things aren't cut off at 80 characters - but the default Terminal and iTerm2 config makes it hard to distinguish between:

- the second line of a wrapped long line
- the start of the next line

Eg:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. 
Proin sed velit nibh. Proin ornare nisi 
at erat congue, vel dignissim tortor malesuada.
```

Is there any way I can configure the app to show things so that there's some space after each carriage return, eg:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. 

Proin sed velit nibh. Proin ornare nisi 
at erat congue, vel dignissim tortor malesuada.
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starting point.

In [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) go to Preferences > Profiles > (Your profile) > Advanced, then click Edit under Triggers.

Add a new Trigger using the + button at the bottom left, then set:

- Regular Expression: `.$`
- Action: `Highlight Text…`
- Parameters: `Red on White` (or a colour combination you find appropriately funkadelic)

Close the Triggers pane.

You should now see a white "line" at the far right of the iTerm window. This is really iTerm changing the last character on the line to red text on a white background. This should help you spot lines that are wrapped versus new lines.

Example screen grab below (I use [fish shell](http://fishshell.com), btw)…

[image: Screen grab of iTerm2 fish shell showing use of Triggers to highlight text]

Answer (score 0):

One way around this would be to pipe your output through **sed G** to double-space the output, example:

```
cat file-with-long-lines.txt | sed G
```

Of course this modifies the output.

Comment: Ack, sed or tr would turn 1 CR into two, however I don't want to have to send stderr to stdout and use sed/tr on every command (and there's a lot of commands).